# How to make responsive data tables expanded by default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

Here's the script I am using for my data tables. Basically on mobile or smaller screen every row childs which are columns are hidden by default with +,- button to expand and see them. I can toggle this to expand and hide function on every row. I want to keep this functionality and make all rows expanded by default not hidden.

[Here is the screenshot of datatable and the problem I want to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWwGQ.png)

[How they look by default as I want them to be expanded by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4vPe.png)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>


 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#table_id').DataTable({
  "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
  "pageLength": 10,
  "info": false,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "responsive": true,
  language: {
    'paginate': {
      'previous': '<span class="prev-icon"><i class="bi bi-chevron-left"></i></span>',
      'next': '<span class="next-icon"><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></span>'
    }
  }
}).colums.adjust().responsive.recalc();
```

});

Comment: Have you tried using `display: DataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate`? See the official documentation for an example here: [Immediately show hidden details](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/immediateShow.html). If that does not meet your needs, you can [edit] your question to show what you tried & explain where you are still having a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for the support I tried this and it solved my problem.

table.rows().every(function () {
    $(this.node()).find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
});

Answer (score 0):

This simulating click on buttons solved my problem to expand them by default.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "pageLength": 10,
    "info": false,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "responsive": true,
    language: {
        'paginate': {
            'previous': '<span class="prev-icon"><i class="bi bi-chevron-left"></i></span>',
            'next': '<span class="next-icon"><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></span>'
        }
    }
});

table.rows().every(function () {
    $(this.node()).find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
});

table.columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();     });
```